# How to Generate Report table [SSRS] for the Query which returns different columns based on parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have prepared a Dynamic Stored Procedure where it returns some set of different columns based on the parameters passed to it.

This Procedure will be having some set of common columns and based on the parameter it returns some more (there is no specific numbers defined to it)

All the calculation are done in the Procedure itself, I just want to render the query which is returned from procedure into the return.

Can this be possible ? Please suggest. 
Thanks in advance for your valuable help.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS isn't going to work for this unless you make the stored procedure return column names that are the same each time. SSRS reports need to know the names of the dataset columns ahead of time for them to report.